# CSS text overflowing when it's supposed to wrap

Tags: html, css, overflow, word-wrap

I am currently working on this page: http://andreafisherdesign.com/wp/about/

The website is designed to be responsive.  When the browser window is re-sized to mobile device width ranges, some text wraps fine while some words overflow. (ctrl+f find "elegant space" on the page and adjust the browser window to watch this in action)

I've noticed that removing the border-image solves the problem.

I cannot use word-wrap:break-word because my client doesn't want the words to be broken in strange parts -- just for the words to descend to the next line.

divs that are involved: 
.content_1, 
article
& p

I don't want to post any specific code since I'm not exactly sure which part is incorrect.

If you do need more information let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the non-breaking spaces. [image]